# Kernel panic on boot: run-init: /sbin/init: No such file or directory

Tags: 14.04, boot, kernel, init

I'm trying to reboot a system Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit. When I boot up, it gives me the message found below.

```
Kernel panic on boot: run-init: /sbin/init: No such file or directory.
```

How can I fix it and restore the original sbin/init?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Boot your linux distribution on USB or CD
2. Live boot your system on the USB or CD key
3. In command line type: `sudo mount /dev/sda1` or your dist partition `/mnt`
4. Run command: `sudo chroot /mnt`
5. Then run: `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`

   Edit in file

   ```
   nameserver 8.8.8.8
   ```
6. `sudo apt-get install init`

After reboot your system, It will work fine.

Comment: It is not possible (anymore) to install the init package, however, I just had to manually link init to `upstart` if that's still on your system. In a chrooted environment: `ln -s /sbin/upstart /sbin/init` and `ln -s /lib/sysvinit/telinit /sbin/telinit`

Comment: Are steps 1 and 2 the same?  If not, I don't understand step 2.