# Ubuntu 16.04 boot stuck, recovery mode encounters kernel panic

Tags: boot, 16.04, kernel

Last night, I shut down my computer (running Ubuntu 16.04) normally and went to bed. This morning, I tried to boot Ubuntu and I encountered this:
 [Image: Ubuntu boot stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIEMt.jpg).

Ubuntu won't boot and recovery mode encounters a kernel panic. It says **/sbin/init: No such a file or directory** and I tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833735/kernel-panic-on-boot-run-init-sbin-init-no-such-file-or-directory) (that I found on multiples sites). It says init is already installed. Also, I tried boot-repair and after that I am facing the same problem as before. It seems files are OK, software is up-to-date. Please help!

Edit: I'm trying to upload a picture to show what the kernel panic looks like but I can't. It says there is a problem with Imgur

Comment: What happens if you try and boot a prior kernel from the GRUB menu?

Comment: @heynnema it goes directly to kernel panic

Comment: See my partial answer... we'll go from there.

Answer (score 0):

## Partial answer... work in progress...

Since you can't get to recovery mode, lets try and check your file system using external media.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` # replacing X with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`