# "Error while loading shared libraries: Invalid ELF header" after replacing the disk

Tags: boot, kernel

I had to move my ssd to the other laptop of the same (!) model.

After that startup started hanging eternally, shell ends up with an error like

*run-init: /sbin/init: No such file or directory*

*Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!*

Every step I take (such as boot-repair) finishes with an error with some of the libraries from /lib/ "Error while loading shared libraries: Invalid ELF header". I can mount the drive, but if I try **chroot** (like proposed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833735/kernel-panic-on-boot-run-init-sbin-init-no-such-file-or-directory)), I see the same error about ELF headers. I've tried fsck -f (couple of errors found, but didn't help)

Both systems (on ssd -- Ubuntu 16.04, and on rescue usb -- Mint 18) are x64.

What can be the problem with the libraries, what can I try? I still hope not to have  everything reinstalled...

Comment: No, it's not. In my case chroot (that is solution in that question) doesn't happen because of this very problem, which is the main thing I ask

Comment: First boot a Linux distribution like the Ubuntu installation USB from a live USB or CD, then chroot from the live USB/CD.

Comment: Well, that's definitely what I'm doing. Not making any sense.